# Using table of contents in without article.cls

Tags: table-of-contents, article, journal-publishing

I'm using the `ametsoc.cls` which is available from [this website](https://www.ametsoc.org/index.cfm/ams/publications/authors/journal-and-bams-authors/latex-author-info/preparing-a-latex-manuscript-for-submission/).  This `.cls` does not call `article.cls`.  I would like to display a table of contents.  As far as I can tell, `ametsoc.cls` does not provide a means to do this.  Is there a package I can call to have the command `\tableofcontents` yield a toc?

Comment: If the `.cls` does not provide `\tableofcontents`, it is most likely, that this is not desired and any article providing a `ToC` might be rejected. But here is a very simple version: `\makeatletter\newcommand{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}\makeaother`, assuming that `ametsoc.cls` has not screwed up `\@starttoc` as well ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  A few comments: The used case is for structuring, toc call would be removed in final iterations.  Your `\makeatother` above is missing a `t`.  Your code causes something like a toc to appear in the compiled document, but it is not well formed, there do not appear to be any line breaks.

Comment: Oh, yes, the missing `t` is  a typo of course, as for the other issues: If the class does not support a toc, chances are quite high that there are no formatting macros for the ToC

Comment: You could try tocloft.  IIRC, it completely replaces the existing TOC code (if you had any).

Comment: Looked into tocloft.  So it would be used to coax the toc outputted due to Christian's fix into something legible?

Comment: @JohnChris - I was hoping it would provide the missing `\l@section` etc. commands as well.  OTOH, it appears to be document class sensitive.